# Print SQL Queries from Access in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, printing

I'm writing a program in C# that interacts with an Access Database. In this database, there are queries already set up. Is it possible to print the tables those queries create in Access from my program (in other words, an Access print dialog comes up with the query-created table)? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Thank you.

Note: the database file is a .mdb file.

Comment: How about putting a datagrid on your form and populating it, then printing the form.

Comment: I was looking into that (using datagridview, though), but the code was getting a little complicated, and I like to keep my code as simple as possible. And since the queries are already created in Access, I was wondering if I could just print the already created queries without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Not much is simple with a datagrid.  Its your code pattern that makes it easier to work with, though I like to avoid datagrids as well.  The automation that @Josh mentions might be a good way, but its still quite complicated.  I think you are better off thinking of it in terms of a report, users dont usually like data just spat out on a page.  Looking into reporting software might not go amiss.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are describing is Access Automation.

MSDN has a number of helpful articles on the subject, including

[How to automate Microsoft Access by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317114)

Specifically, check the section titled **Print or Preview an Access Report**